# Should I create a table which only has id and name and belongs to users table with one to one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new to sql and I need help designing my tables.  Here is one scenario:

I've a user table.  Each user can belong to only one community out of about 600 communities.  In users table I will have a community_id.  When fetching user information on a website, I will get the community_id.  Which of the following options is better:

1. Should i have a javascript object that maps community_id to a specific community name.  This way I won't need to create a table in SQL?
2. Should I create a another table in sql, and get community_name from table association? One user has one community (users table has community_id as foreign key)
3. Or instead of saving as community_id in user table, should I just store the community_name string.  Does it become harder to search by community string vs integer?

Is one or the other a bad idea?  What is the best practice of doing such operation? Mostly I'll be doing a lot of read rather than write?

Please don't delete this question, as I'm very confused with how to structure a database.  Getting help from best people would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you just listed every database you know? Please remove those tags if your question is not about a specific database.

Comment: Read up on database normalisation. There are millions of references, for example http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Comment: Thanks @crafter, I've tried but practical situation like this is not explained well in too many places.  I wanted to know if it was a good idea to create a table, or instead just handle same key/value pair in javascript itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is bad. You need to change the code every time you add a community.

Option 2 is the best option. To add a community, you just have to insert a row. You can even make an admin window to do that, so you don't even have to do it directly in the database. 
A join in SQL is simple to make, and the relation is easy to enforce with a foreign key constraint.

Option 3 is bad. If a community name changes, you would have to update all users that are in that community. In a properly normalized database, the community would be stored in a separate table. It's likely that you are going to add extra fields too for a community, and you wouldn't want to add them all the the users table.

Comment: Thanks, now that you have provided drawbacks of each, it makes sense.

Comment: Of course it's really one to many, in the sense that one community can have many members.

Comment: Only reason I was tempted to use first option is because I need to show those 600 communites on the UI so user can choose one of them.  If I created a javascript object rather than reading from table then it would be one less query per page load.

Comment: If a user can have one community anyway, you probably will only show that list when they change their profile or something, so you don't need the query on *every* page load. That aside, two queries still isn't much, and if needed you can add *paging* or *infinite scroll* to your pages. Also, you can cache query results using memcache, or even do store them as JavaScript options, but automatically update the file from the database when you add or change a community only. But you know what they say about premature optimization..

Comment: @Strawberry Of course. Brainfart. I've changed that phrase.

Comment: Also, I suggest adding a unique constraint of community name.

Comment: Great response @GolezTrol, I've a single page application.  So I would have to load on every page load. However as you mentioned caching would be a great way to reduce the load!!! THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a separate table of communities.

The problem with using a name instead of an id as a Primary key is that names change.

Comment: @crafter This is a short answer. Nevertheless, it *IS* an *answer*, and *NOT* a *comment* ;-)

Comment: OK, I get you. I'm not going to ague this - it was a suggestion, not meant to detract from your contribution. I will delete both my comments once I think you have read my input,